# How do I solve this form issue with JSP using AJAX?

Tags: java, ajax

I want to send data from a form to a Servlet using Ajax, but when I made a check about the data that was being serialized using the jQuery .serialize() function, I noticed that it wasn't taking the value of the file field. In a previous test I got an error with a message like this: the request was rejected because there was no multipart data found

The following is the form HTML code:

```
<form id="frmCrcnCaso" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input id="txtNoVlt" name="txtNoVlt" type="text" class="form-control">
   <input id="txtNmr" name="txtNmr" type="text" class="form-control">
   <input id="txtFchOfc" name="txtFchOfc" type="date" class="form-control">
   <input id="flAcvAjt" name="flAcvAjt" type="file" class="form-control"/>
</form>
<button id="btnGuardar" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
    Guardar
</button>
```

And this is the javascript code:

```
$("#btnGuardar").on("click",function(){
    ValidarGuardado();
});

function ValidarGuardado(){
  ...
  // Activar el guardado
  Guardar();         
}// </editor-fold>

function Guardar(){
     $(...).append("...
         <button id='btnGdrCaso' type='button' class='btn btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Guardar</button>\n\
      ...");

     $(...).modal();

     $("#btnGdrCaso").on("click",function(){
         ...
         var datosCaso = $("#frmCrcnCaso").serialize();
         ...
         $.ajax({
             url: "GuardarCaso" // Servlet name,
             type: "POST",
             contentType : false,
             data: datosCaso,             
             success:function(r){
                 if(r === "1"){
                     ...
                 }else if(r === "2"){
                     ...
                 }else{
                     ...
                 }
             },
             error:function(r){
                 ...
             }
         });
     });
}
```

Comment: `contentType : false` doesn't help for sure

Comment: Did you try with contentType: "multipart/form-data" in your request? Not sure if it would help.

Comment: Yes I did. But the thing is that the file field doesn't seem to be included with the others when I send the data.